# Naming a variable that store a result of a function with the same meaning

Tags: c++

I know it sound silly, but I wonder how other people are solving this.

Say I have a function `isOnMoon()` and I want to store the result in a variable to use it multiple time in, let's say, C++ code.

If I'll do

```
bool isOnMoon = isOnMoon();
```

It will not work, with the failure `Error: Only a function may be called.`

And then I resort to `isOnMoonVal` or `onMoon` - so I just wonder what how are you naming this?

Comment: just give it a different name.

Comment: Including the scope might help `bool isOnMoon = ::isOnMoon();`. But generally a bad practice to reuse names.

Comment: If `isOnMoon()` a simple getter, variable is not really needed. if there is some computation, I like to name the method accordingly (`computeIsOnMoon`) (so verb vs name to avoid the problem).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isOnMoon=IsOnMoon();
```

You have to rename one of them because you can't have two entities with the same name. I personally use this method: for functions I use the upper case on all the initials of the function name: IsOnMoon(). for variables I use the uppur case in every initial except in the first initial: isOnMoon.

Comment: this is good, unfortunately I'm working on very big code base with naming rules that have functions and variable follow the same rules. But I agree this is a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two entities with the same name in the same scope. Rename one of them. It is as simple as that.

Names can hide other names as in

```
int foo;
{
   int foo;
}
```

But this is not recommended and there is no way to access the `foo` from the outer scope in the inner scope.